# NetBeans подстановка переменных

Tags: netbeans

Добрый день!
Решил попробывать netbeans, создал проект с удаленным кодом.
Сразу возник вопрос - как сделать так, что бы при вводе первых символов переменной или названия класса или функции был выбор подходящих названи1, как в ZDE, например ввожу MySQL и ниже выводится посветка всех функций начинающихся с этой фразы?

Comment: Речь идет о стандартных функциях php или о функциях, определенных в других файлах вашего проекта?

Comment: ctrl+space разве не работает?

Comment: в других файлах

Comment: Работает, спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос решен - Ctrl+Space после ввода нескольких символов надо нажать.

Comment: Ещё Editor -> Code completion -> Language -> Java -> Auto Popup onTyping... если нужна автоматическая сортировка.